# How to get the Date time month start and End Date?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

How to get the start date and end date of month in different variable. I have tried this and I get the start date but unable to find the end date

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
DateTime  endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1).AddDays(30).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

This logic fails when month end date is 31 and 28 or 29. Your Help are surely appretiated.

Comment: A month day always starts `1` but it can be ends with `28`, `29`, `30` or `31`. As far as I know, most logical way will be adding `1` month to your start date and subtract `1` day with it.

Comment: Side Note: Please don't use some `DateTime.Now`s in your code, instead declare a variable to store it - `var now = DateTime.Now;` - then use that variable instead ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29530946/4519059));)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can calculate `endDate` like this:

```
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: @SonerGönül Downvoter can have multiple reasons. For example he can say that the original code wouldn't compile because of `.ToString()` so my code wouldn't compile as well. Or anything else.

Answer (score 17):

To get First Date

```
public DateTime FirstDayOfMonth(DateTime dateTime)
{
   return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
}
```

To get Last Date

```
public DateTime LastDayOfMonth(DateTime dateTime)
{
   DateTime firstDayOfTheMonth = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
   return firstDayOfTheMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
}
```

Comment: I'd use the first function in the second one.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1)
                       .AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You already had the start date :

```
DateTime monthStartDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
```

There's a method to get the number of days in a month (and Looking at the IL code, it seems that this way is more efficient than the other answers, though unless you're going to do it a billion time, I doubt there will be any difference) :

```
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month);
DateTime monthEndDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, daysInMonth);
```

Answer (score -2):

For first date:

```
DateTime first_date = new DateTime(DateTimePicker.Value.Year, DateTimePicker.Value.Month, 1);
```

For last date:

```
DateTime last_date = new DateTime(DateTimePicker.Value.Year, DateTimePicker.Value.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTimePicker.Value.Year, DateTimePicker.Value.Month));
```

Comment: What is difference of your answer to [this answer in 2 years earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23077662/4519059)?