# How can `DateTime.Now - DateTimeNow.AddSecond(-1)` be zero

Tags: c#, datetime

I run below code in a console application:

```
while (true)
{
    DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1);

    if ((dt1 - dt2).Seconds != 1)
        Console.Write((dt1 - dt2).Seconds.ToString());
}
```

And I thought `(dt1 - dt2).Seconds` is always `1` but as I saw it write many `0` in the output !!??

Why does `(dt1 - dt2).Seconds` become `0` ?

---

Then I try below code:

```
if ((dt1.Hour * 3600 - dt2.Hour * 3600 + dt1.Minute * 60 - dt2.Minute * 60 + dt1.Second - dt2.Second) != 1)
    Console.Write((dt1.Second - dt2.Second).ToString());
```

And this new code say may `(dt1.Hour * 3600 - dt2.Hour * 3600 + dt1.Minute * 60 - dt2.Minute * 60 + dt1.Second - dt2.Second)` is always `1` (However I know in `23:59:59` => `00:00:00` it should write a value)

Comment: I see that you answers can remove those `0` from output, But I wonder to know why the next code don't make `0` in output when it's also using dt1 and dt2? ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you evaluate your `DateTime.Now` value again for your `dt2` variable, that's why this little difference is completely expected. That means your second `DateTime.Now` calculated at least 1 [`Tick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) and at most 10 million `Ticks` (which is equal to 1 second) after the first one.

And since [`DateTime.Second` property](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,990) calculated with `InternalTicks` and `TicksPerSecond`, it returns zero when `InternalTicks` is less than `TicksPerSecond` value after calcualte remainder with `60`.

```
public int Second
{
     get
     {
        return (int)((InternalTicks / TicksPerSecond) % 60); 
     }
}
```

If you use same `DateTime.Now` value for both variable, that should be ok.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dt1 = now;
DateTime dt2 = now.AddSeconds(-1);
```

> Why (dt1.Hour * 3600 - dt2.Hour * 3600 + dt1.Minute * 60 - dt2.Minute
>   * 60 + dt1.Second - dt2.Second) is always 1?

*Well*, it is **not** always `1`. Let's assume your first `DateTime.Now` (which is `dt1`) generates `00:00:00.00000`. And second `DateTime.Now` generates `00:00:00.00002` (those are theoretical values) and your `dt2` will be `23:59:59.002`.

Let's look at the `Hours`, `Minute` and `Second` values;

```
dt1.Hour = 0;
dt2.Hour = 23;
dt1.Minute = 0;
dt2.Minute = 59;
dt1.Second = 0;
dt2.Second = 59;
```

And the result of `dt1.Hour * 3600 - dt2.Hour * 3600 + dt1.Minute * 60 - dt2.Minute * 60 + dt1.Second - dt2.Second)` will be `-86399` not `1`.

Comment: I see that you answer can remove those `0` from output, But I wonder to know why the next code don't make `0` in output when it's also using dt1 and dt2? ;).

Comment: And I should never use `if (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1))` ;).

Comment: @shA.t Added more explanation why it will **not** return `1` always.

Comment: @shA.t Exactly. Because even if they will be on the same line, both `DateTime.Now` _may_ not generate the same results since they are evulated left to right since `-` operator is left-associative,

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this

```
 DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime dt2 = dt1.AddSeconds(-1);
```

You have initialized 2 different timestamps (which vary by a tiny fraction of time), when you accessed the `DateTime.Now`.